# Too much wasted space between question and answer input form because of moved 'Related questions' from side to center

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Yes, title says it all:

The new 'Related questions' section moves the answer box more to the end of page and makes it problematic to write an answer with code and have a look to a wanted result from the question.

Please return to the old layout.

BTW why is no tag for [workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflow)?

Comment: Another UI element to add to my Ad Blocker for now, I suppose.

Comment: Idea: Add an option to settings for users to be able to move it back to the side. This will allow people who like the change to keep it, and people who don’t to be able to revert it.

Comment: Is it just me, or are the "Related questions" not related at all to the question being asked. For example, there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806544). How is the top link to a question about `a[5] == [5]a` even remotely related to compiling a source file on Alpine Linux. Seems to me that the heading "Related questions" would be more informative if it was changed to "Completely irrelevant questions"

Comment: @user3386109 as related as google image searching for "X" and returning 100 images of "Y" and "Z" just becuase there __has__ to be some results. If none found, pick random.

Answer (score 18):

For me it's not that it moves the answer box, it's that it's a large amount of visually-distracting stuff in a large font and with highlighted URLs, front-and-centre where I'm used to looking for comments (and existing answers). I use the dark theme, in case that matters.  Hmm, am I imagining things or did the fonts (especially for the links) just get smaller in the past minute?

Maybe something my brain can learn to visually ignore, but I'd much rather have the option of putting it back on the side.  (@Fastnlight commented with that suggestion of an option to control where it goes, although I suspect that the SE devs would rather not maintain and test 2 versions of the layout.)

---

Also, the relatedness of the Related Questions list would need to go up a huge amount before it makes any sense to give them any more prominence than they have in the sidebar.  Usually it's "some random popular questions with some overlap in tags"; only occasionally is one actually related.  It does happen, though.  So the default should be at the side.

Comment: "*I suspect that the SE devs would rather not maintain and test 2 versions of the layout.*" no reason to worry - they don't really maintain the one we have now. And the testing is done live on prod by users of the system anyway. I'm at least mostly joking.

Comment: I think the "Related questions" should just be removed altogether. In my experience, it's extraordinarily rare that a link in the "Related questions" actually leads to a question that's relevant. Case in point would be the [four "Related" questions listed on the side of this meta question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okISl.png).

Comment: @user3386109 In my experience for very obvious duplicates, they can be very on point and specific. I find them occasionally helpful to be able to close as a duplicate without searching on DuckDuckGo.

Comment: I only see Related questions below answers when there is no answer, yet. On questions with answers Related questions are on a side, like they used to be.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, even if so, the answering is much mor complicated as before in terms of worksflow without scolling.

Comment: @NinaScholz "*the answering is much mor complicated as before in terms of worksflow without scolling.*" you can enable keyboard shortcuts if you go in your profile. With keyboard shortcuts, you can press **a** to directly focus the answer box. This is in no way an endorsement of the related questions being in the middle of the page but a *workaround* for slightly easier navigation in the page.

Comment: IMO you will never, ever, ever convince the staff to remove a feature that links pages to each other with any plausible justification, given their financial incentive to get people to visit more pages and thus see more ads.

Comment: I know it's not the trend of websites - but why not simply make this a checkbox in your user profile. Set this on by default. And allow users to switch off.